# Development machine setup - shifting from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, development

I am liking Windows 7 (using, 7600-RTM), mainly because of the window-snapping feature, especially the 50%-two windows on the desktop feature. It does increase productivity. Plus, at times, I have to use Word '07 and very rarely fireworks. That is why I am temporarily shifting to Windows 7.

I am trying to set up Linux in VirtualBox as I am totally new to virtualisation software.

Things I have done:

- Chose grml, a Debian-based (because of super-duper apt-engine) light-weight system-tools distro.
- Installed VirtualBox and made a new 3GB dynamic HDD image for it. I mounted my grml-medium-2009.10.iso, live-booted from it, at shell, cfdisk, made a 3GB partition (it showed 3GB from the virtual HDD of VirtualBox then grml2hd (to install grml on hard-disk). I included Debian repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list. sudo apt-get install build-essential lxde manpages-posix-dev, etc.

The machine is up, but I have some questions:

- I am unable to run my grml in full-screen mode.
  <kbd>hostkey</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> gives a black screen, but grml is still running in some reduced resolution.
- How do you share files between guest and the host OS (the best/easiest or the recommended way)?
- I am a network n systems programmer, so what best tools do you suggest I use, apart from nmap, ethereal-wireshark, and iptables?
- Is there a way to ssh to my grml from Windows?
- What are your favorite VirtualBox addons?
- What are best practices or advice from your experience?

Answer (score 1):

> But not able to run my grml is full-screen mode, hostkey+F give a black screen, but grml is still running in some reduced resolution.

To be able to do so you have to install the Guest Additions modules, check out the documentation or forums of that distro for info on it, the installation may vary.

Generally you just have to be running the VM and select `Install Guest Additions` from the `Devices` menu of the VM. This will "insert" a CD in the VM in which you will find a file to install them. You may recognize the file by its file name (i.e.: VBoxLinuxAdditions-amd64.run for a 64-bit Linux OS).

The installation will build some modules, make sure you have GCC and the Kernel headers installed in your VM Linux.

> how do you i share files between guest and host os, the best/easiest or the recommended way.

The easiest way with VBox at the time of writing is to create a shared folder between the host OS and the VM. To do so add a folder in the `Shared Folders` tab of the configuration of your VM.

To mount it use `mount -t vboxsf folder_name mount_point`, you must have the Guest Additions modules installed to be able to use shared folders.

If you need something easier VMware allows drag-and-drop once the guest tools are installed, VBox hasn't implemented that just yet.

> I am a network n systems programmer, what best tools you suggest for me to use, apart from nmap, ethereal-wireshar, and iptables.

Sorry apart from those I can't help but I'd like to know it too.

> Is there a way to ssh to my grml from windows.

I've never tried it but I bet it is, the VM will share a network with the host OS (through a virtual adapter), so using the VMs IP you could do it. It's most likely you can do that.

> What are virtualbox addons, your favourites.

I don't use any addons... But I don't make an extensive use of VBox either. What it provides is enough just for me.

> What are best practices, or advices from your experience.

Nothing remarkable in my experience I'm afraid.